# Detect when the WebView finishes loading in Swift4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I want to display progress while the WebView is loading and dismiss it when the WebView finishes loading.
I tried this code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import SVProgressHUD
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var WebView1: WKWebView!
@IBOutlet var WebView2: WKWebView!


let YouTubeURL = URL (string: "https://www.youtube.com/")


@IBAction func YTButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let YTRequest = URLRequest(url: YouTubeURL!)
    WebView1.load(YTRequest)
    if WebView1.isLoading {
        SVProgressHUD.show()
    }
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(WebView1 : UIWebView) {

        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

    }


}
}
```

But it doesn't work.
The progress continue rotating.
Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to set the delegate to connect to the webViewDidFinishLoad function. Also, UIWebView is deprecated as an FYI.

Comment: precisely, you need the delegate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three fatal issues:

- You have to set the delegate

  ```
  WebView1.delegate = self
  ```
- The signature of the delegate method is wrong

  ```
  func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)
  ```
- The delegate method must be on the top level of the class.

I think there is a fourth fatal issue: I doubt that `WKWebView` conforms to `UIWebViewDelegate` at all. I suppose you have to adopt `WKNavigationDelegate` and implement `webView(:didFinish:)` instead.

And please conform to the Swift naming convention that variable and function / method names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: I've never seen so many problems, explained so clearly and concisely !  :)

Comment: Thank you @vadian, but when i write the delegate in "viewdidload" Xcode shows "Value of type 'WKWebView' has no member 'delegate' ", I changed the 'UIWebViewDelegate' to 'WKNavigationDelegate'.

Comment: The name of the `WKWebView` property is `navigationDelegate`

Comment: What should I do ?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, `WKWebView` does not conform to `UIWebViewDelegate`. Please note my suggestion.

Comment: Can you please rewrite the code, I didn't get it ^_^.

Comment: Replace `UIWebViewDelegate` with `WKNavigationDelegate`. Replace `WebView1.delegate = self` with `WebView1.navigationDelegate = self`. And rather than `webViewDidFinishLoad` implement `webView(:didFinish:`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer :
I changed

1. > **UIWebViewDelegate** to **WKNavigationDelegate**
2. > **WebView1.delegate = self** to **WebView1. navigationDelegate = self**
   >   The name of the WKWebView property is navigationDelegat
3. > **func webViewDidFinishLoad(WebView1 : UIWebView)** to 
   >   **func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
   >                didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)**